# How can I connect to 2 kafka topics at a time, but process only 1 at a time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to know how I can connect to 2 kafka topics from within a single spark stream job, but only process the messages of 1 of the topics at a time.

I want the ability to process from topic#1, and based on some condition I would then switch to process topic#2.

How can I do that in spark?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just create two streaming context objects and gracefully stop and start the streams when you need to change topics.

Answer (score 0):

For test I use queueStream

```
data = 'abcdefgh'
rddQueue1 = map(lambda x: sc.parallelize(x), zip(*[iter(data)] * 2))
rddQueue2 = map(lambda x: sc.parallelize(x), zip(*[iter(data.upper())] * 2))

s1, s2 = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue1), ssc.queueStream(rddQueue2)

s3 = s1.transformWith(lambda t, x, y: x if int(str(t)[-1]) % 2 else y, s2)
```

And KafkaUtils also supports DStream.transformWith()